# nested clob xmlelemnt oracle sql select

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I get this error when trying to run this sql scrip, I've searched alot for converting clob to varchar2 but useless

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

```
SELECT  XMLELEMENT("ejada:PrivilegeResourcesList",XMLATTRIBUTES(NOENTITYESCAPING  GET_MCR_PARAMETER('xmlns:core') AS "xmlns:core", GET_MCR_PARAMETER('xmlns:ejada') AS "xmlns:ejada"),
        XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("ejada:PrivilegeResourcesInfo",XMLELEMENT("ejada:PrivilegeRec",
        XMLELEMENT("ejada:FuncId","F_CODE"),
        XMLELEMENT("ejada:SCId","PS_CHANNEL_ID"),
        XMLELEMENT("ejada:SrcResourcesList","SRCLIST"),
        XMLELEMENT("ejada:TargResourcesList","TRGLIST"),
        XMLELEMENT("ejada:Status","PS_STATUS")

                       )))) .GETCLOBVAL()
        INTO P_PRIVILEGE_RESOURCES_LIST
        from (
        SELECT distinct  
        F_CODE, PS_CHANNEL_ID,
        (
          SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("core:ResourceInfo",XMLELEMENT ("core:ResourceId", 
          DECODE(PR_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID,
          '1', XMLELEMENT("core:AcctId",XMLELEMENT("core:AcctId","PR_RESOURCE_VALUE")), 
          '2', XMLELEMENT("core:BillId",XMLELEMENT("core:BillNum","PR_RESOURCE_VALUE")),
          '3', XMLELEMENT("core:BenId",XMLELEMENT("core:BenCode","PR_RESOURCE_VALUE"))
          ))
          ,XMLELEMENT("core:ResourceType","PRT_RESOUCE_TYPE_NAME_E")

          )).GETCLOBVAL() FROM(SELECT PR_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID, PR_RESOURCE_VALUE, PRT_RESOUCE_TYPE_NAME_E FROM PERMISSION_RESOURCES, PERM_RESOURCE_TYPES WHERE PR_PERMISSION_ID = P.PS_PERMISSION_ID AND PR_USAGE_TYPE = 'S' AND PR_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID = PRT_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID) 
        ) SRCLIST,
        (
          SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("core:ResourceInfo",XMLELEMENT ("core:ResourceId", 
          DECODE(PR_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID,
          '1', XMLELEMENT("core:AcctId",XMLELEMENT("core:AcctId","PR_RESOURCE_VALUE")), 
          '2', XMLELEMENT("core:BillId",XMLELEMENT("core:BillNum","PR_RESOURCE_VALUE")),
          '3', XMLELEMENT("core:BenId",XMLELEMENT("core:BenCode","PR_RESOURCE_VALUE"))
          ))
          ,XMLELEMENT("core:ResourceType","PRT_RESOUCE_TYPE_NAME_E")

          )).GETCLOBVAL() FROM(SELECT PR_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID, PR_RESOURCE_VALUE, PRT_RESOUCE_TYPE_NAME_E FROM PERMISSION_RESOURCES, PERM_RESOURCE_TYPES WHERE PR_PERMISSION_ID = P.PS_PERMISSION_ID AND PR_USAGE_TYPE = 'D' AND PR_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID = PRT_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID)
        ) TRGLIST,
        PS_STATUS



         FROM FUNCTIONS F , SERVICES S ,    PERMISSIONS P
         WHERE PS_STATUS             = 'A'
          --AND PS_COMP_TYPE_ID               = v_component_type
          -- AND Ps_COMPONENT_ID                    = v_component_id
           AND PS_ROLE_ID = P_ROLE_ID
           AND PS_ROLE_ID IN (SELECT R_ROLE_ID 
                                 FROM ROLES 
                                  WHERE R_ROLE_ID=P_ROLE_ID AND
                                  R_COMP_TYPE_ID = 'ORGZ' AND
                                  R_COMPONENT_ID= P_ORG_ID)
           AND PS_FUNCTION_ID                     = F_code
           AND F_SERVICE_ID                       = S_SERVICE_ID   
--           AND PS_PERMISSION_ID                   = PR_PERMISSION_ID

         ORDER BY F_CODE
         ) ;
```

Comment: So what is the datatype of `P_PRIVILEGE_RESOURCES_LIST`.  Is it a CLOB ???

Comment: Also, you do realise that this is a horribly complicated chunk of XML Query?    It's quite presumptive to think we'll invest our time unpicking all those nested sub-queries and trying to figure out what's going on.  You should have invested your time in producing a simpler test case which reproduces your problem without requiring so much effort from us.  Apart from anything else, if you had done that exercise you might have discovered what the problem was all by yourself.